# Why does javascript execution affect css animation and animated gif in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

There's a big question for me which always comes on when I work on asynchronous loading of data e.g. an image with javascript.
In the past I placed a loader to show the user that something is in progress. 
But at the time the data is loading the image won't animate properly. It's bucking all the time but only in Firefox Browser.

Same problem is with css3 animations e.g. a rotation.

Why is that happening?

```
var imgUrl = 'http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA13932.jpg';
var aImagesToLoad = [];
var iLoaded = 0;
var runs = 3;

$(document).on('click', 'a#init-load', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('A big image is loaded three times now')) {
        var i, j;
        var self = $(this);

        self.fadeOut(500);  
        $('img').addClass('show');

        for ( i = 0; i < runs; i += 1) {
            var ts = new Date().getTime();

            aImagesToLoad.push(new Image());
            aImagesToLoad[aImagesToLoad.length - 1].onload = function(load) {
                iLoaded += 1;

                if (iLoaded === runs - 1) {
                    $('img').removeClass('show');
                    self.fadeIn(500);
                }
             };

             aImagesToLoad[aImagesToLoad.length - 1].src = imgUrl + '?uq=' + (ts + i);
         }
    }
});
```

Made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esAGA/3/) with an ajaxloader image (animated gif) and a css rotation animation. Where it can be tested.

Comment: No problem for me on last version of FireFox.

Comment: @TigOldBitties Using also newest Firefox on a new MacbookPro Retina and compared to a Webkit Browser ist bucking.

Comment: Looks like a browser issue to me.

Comment: @TigOldBitties It's a plain firefox without any addons

Comment: im not seeing this issue on latest firefox 24.. when i take out your confirm() it loads fine also .. http://jsfiddle.net/esAGA/11/ -

Comment: Yes it loads but the animation is not running linear it blocks serveral times. Then it runs fine a while and then there are problems again.

Comment: @Bernhard just added my answer below on how to trigger hardware acceleration in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you neeed to add **transalte3d(0,0,0)** in your stylesheet so it kick in hardware acceleration  rendering:

for example try:

```
transform: scale(1) rotate(359deg) translate3d(0,0,0.1);
```

the **translate3d()** property tells the browser to use hardware acceleration for smoother animation

```
#css-ajaxloader {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate3d(0,0,0.1);
}
```

also i specify the scale at its default so the browser does not inherit any other scale.. since we want the scale at its default value of 1 .. normal size

adding **Z** to **0.1** will kick in hardware acceleration if the browser supports it

try that

Comment: when i run this in firefox 24 with firebug disabled it animates fine

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right with that. Runs much better but in webkit it seems to run much smoother but that is a mozilla reason I think.

Comment: have you heard of GSAP.. its a great animation platform and animates elements and CSS properties better than jQuery .. http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/ ..